# Can I apply for a visa while in the US?

Tags: visas, usa

I am already in the US on J-1 status, that expires on July 14. I am about to do a PhD from September on, and I have already obtained the I-20 document.

In general, I am aware of the fact that I'll have to go through an interview at the US embassy in my home country. The question is: Can I submit my application, obtain the DS-160 document, and make an appointment with the US embassy while I am still in the US?

Comment: Nothing stops you from doing so.

Comment: It is not actually necessary to have a valid visa. You can also apply to extend your nonimmigrant status and then get a visa the next time you leave the US.  But this qurestion belongs on [Expatriates.SE].

Comment: You can do it. You do not have to be present in your home country up until the day of the interview. Beware that in some countries you have to arrange visa payments in advance of your appointment through some local channel (specific bank or payment system).
You also can stay in the US, as your status has already been or will be extended.